# How can I solve "Required property not found in json" error without changing the json and its corresponding class?

Tags: c#, json.net

**A)**

I have a DLL library include a class like the bellow code:

```
public class Thing
{
    // OTHER_PROPERTIES

    //..........................

    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public bool IsBook { get; set; }
}
```

> *Assumption:* I have **not** access to the source of the `Thing` class.

---

**B)**

And I have a JSON like this:

```
{
    OTHER_PROPERTIES
}
```

> *Note:* It has **not** a pair of name-value for `IsBook`
>
> *Assumption:* I **wont** change the `JSON` to include `IsBook` in it.

---

**C)**

If I run `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Thing>(json);` then I get the following error:

> *Error:* Required property not found in json ....

---

### Question:

How can I write a custom code to solve the above error by observing the assumptions of the problem?
(please read the above *assumptions* again before writing your answer.)

Comment: Deserialize to an intermediate object (`dynamic` or concrete) and then construct the `Thing` object from the intermediate. The JSON serializer will not work directly because of the required attribute.

Comment: @RonBeyer, Thank you for your reply. I think your solution will works although dynamic properties make it slower but also I want see is there a way by writing a custom settings for `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use custom contract resolver to achieve that. For example:

```
public class Thing
{
    [JsonProperty("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public bool IsBook { get; set; }
}

class NeverRequiredContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver {
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization) {
        var prop = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        prop.Required = Required.Default;
        return prop;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
var test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Thing>("{\"Name\":\"some name\"}",
    new JsonSerializerSettings {
        ContractResolver = new NeverRequiredContractResolver()
    });
```

Of course you can assign resolver globally and not pass it to every `DeserializeObject`:

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    ContractResolver = new NeverRequiredContractResolver()
};
var test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Thing>("{\"Name\":\"some name\"}");
```

you can make only specific properties of specific classes non-required (and not all of them like in example above):

```
class CustomPropertyContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver {
    private readonly Action<MemberInfo, JsonProperty> _propFixup;
    public CustomPropertyContractResolver(Action<MemberInfo, JsonProperty> propFixup) {
        _propFixup = propFixup;
    }
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization) {
        var prop = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        _propFixup?.Invoke(member , prop);
        return prop;
    }
}

JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    ContractResolver = new CustomPropertyContractResolver((member, prop) => {
        if (member.DeclaringType == typeof(Thing) && member.Name == "IsBook") {
            prop.Required = Required.Default;
        }
    })
};
var test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Thing>("{\"Name\":\"some name\"}");
```

and overall adjust example above however you wish for your specific use case.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is right what I want . But I have a question: How should I change your solution to **support nested properties** in a json and  its corresponding Type? For example if `IsBook` is in `Box` class and `MyBox` is defined in `Thing` » `class Thing{ public Box MyBox{get;set;} ....} class Box{ public bool IsBook{get;set;}}`

Comment: Looks like you can change last sample to check for Box type? Or you want to drop required for Box.IsBook only when box is inside Thing?

Comment: I found answer of my last question:  `ContractResolver = new CustomPropertyContractResolver((member, prop) =>{
if (member.DeclaringType == typeof(Box) && member.Name == "IsBook"){prop.Required = Required.Default;prop.DefaultValue = false;}})`. Thank you again for your good answer. It solved my problem. 